# Tensors: traction free planes

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

> Given the following stress tensor matrix, determine the value of $\sigma_{22}$ such that there is a traction free plane and determine the unit normal to this plane.
>   $$
> \sigma_{ij} = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 2 & 1\\
> 2 & \sigma_{22} & 2\\
> 1 & 2 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

---

The Cauchy stress tensor is 
$$
\mathbf{t}^{(n)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 1\\
2 & \sigma_{22} & 2\\
1 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{n}}
$$
If we want a traction free plane, (*this is just a guess*) we want the traction tensor to be zero. **I cant find anything online about this or in my book so I am not to sure about my method.**
Then
$$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}
$$
iff the determinant of $\mathbf{A}$ is zero. Therefore, $\sigma_{22} = 0$. Now we can solve for $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$.
\begin{align}
2n_2 + n_3 &= 0\\
n_2 &= -n_3/2\\
2n_1 + 2n_3 &= 0\\
n_1 &= -n_3\\
n_1 + 2n_2 &= 0\\
n_3 &= 0
\end{align}
The magnitude of $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is $\lVert\hat{\mathbf{n}}\rVert = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ so
$$
\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\langle 2, 1, 0\rangle
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some value of $\sigma_{22}$ for which t=(0,0,0) on some (unknown) plane. 
Since $[t]=[\sigma][n]$, this is equivalent to the condition that the homogeneous linear equation $[\sigma][n]=[0]$ has a non-trivial solution.

This occurs when $\det[\sigma]=0$.

From the component form, evaluating the determinant gives you $0 + 4-\sigma_{22}+4=0$, so the only solution is $\sigma_{22}=8$.

Plug it back in to $[\sigma][n]=[0]$, writing $\hat{n}=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ and you have the linear equations
$$
2 n_2 + n_3 = 0 \\
2 n_1 + 8 n_2 + 2 n_3 = 0
$$
From (1) and (2) you have $n_3=-2n_2$, $n_1=-2n_2$.

Since $\hat{n}$ is a normal vector, you must have $|\hat{n}|=1$. This will finally give you the two unit vectors $\pm (\dfrac{2}{3},\dfrac{-1}{3},\dfrac{2}{3})$.

You can plug the value $\sigma_{22}=8$ and these values of $\hat{n}$ to check that you indeed get zero traction on this plane.

Edited to add: You calculated the determinant incorrectly, so your answer is off.